# Making a copy of an array with Arrays.asList

Tags: java, arrays, collections

so I have an int array, and want to have another array that points to the same values as the original array so that when original array changes the second array would point to to the new value.

I tried with

```
List<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(original array));
secondList = secondList.subList(start,finish);
```

But I get an error that says that .asList returns - list of type int[]
Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any good way to do this?

Comment: let me guess: the original array is decleared as `int[]`? Try declaring it as `Integer[]`

Comment: @Turing85 And how would you go about doing that?

Comment: @AnubianNoob I do not understand... just like every other array: `Integer[] array = new Integer[size];`. You have to initialize each cell with `array[i] = new Integer(value);`.

Comment: You don't need to copy then, you just to create a new reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original array is `int[]`, `Arrays.asList` will return a `List<int[]>`. If the original array will be `Integer[]`, `Arrays.asList` will return a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the second list point to the first with the use of the "=" operator.

For example:

```
List<Integer> firstList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> secondList = firstList;

firstList.add(1);
System.out.println(secondList.size());
```

Will print out "1" as the size of the second list as they both "point" to the same location in memory.

Comment: The first `ist` is not a list, but an array. Therefore, you solution will not work.